# JavaScript onpopstate alternative with same functional like onhashchange

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've search on Google and some other questions in this forum, but it seems not answered my question.

Based on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate :

> Note that just calling `history.pushState()` or `history.replaceState()` won't trigger a `popstate` event. The `popstate` event is only triggered by doing a browser action such as a clicking on the back button (or calling `history.back()` in JavaScript). And the event is only triggered when the user navigates between two history entries for the same document.

I'm looking for `onpopstate` alternative that has the same functional as `window.onhashchange` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange) that will fire the event when the URL changed.

Would you like to share your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably could use the "History.js" tool, which provides a "statechange" event that you can listen for. The tool fires that event either when the forward/backward buttons are pressed or when you use pushState/replaceState.

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Of course, now you've traded for a different problem, which is that you have the event being fired for both types of actions, and you often want to distinguish between them and that's more difficult. So you have to hack your own solution to distinguishing them. Most people seem to set some global flag whenever they are about to call pushState/replaceState, and then check for this flag in the event handler. If the flag is set, then the event came from your own code, if not, it came from the browser buttons.

Comment: Thank you very much mr @kyle-simpson you've visited here. 
i won't use external library just to do simple thing.

But you are true, should hack my own solution. I create own version of pushState. Then, create the Router function that will be called by the `onpopstate` and my own pushState

Comment: lil bit late on the party but I am googling to see alternatives of pushState so I can, on a Reactjs app, make use of pagination without after a page refresh on a custom route, i get a 404. myapp/newpage for ex. Could I make use of this History.js so I can make my own API to manage that?